# Null pointer when Reading text file in java

Tags: java, android

I got Null pointer exception when reading data from file.if its returning a junk value how to handle that. if i didn't give trim giving some junk value. 
My code is:

```
BufferedReader br = null;
try {           
    String sCurrentval = "";
    br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("filepath"));
    while ((sCurrentval = br.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println("Reading from File "+sCurrentval);
    }
    if(sCurrentval != null){
        sCurrentval = sCurrentval.trim();
    }
    System.out.println("outside :  Reading from File "+sCurrentval);
    if(sCurrentval != null && !sCurrentval.equalsIgnorecase("")){
        try{
            val = Integer.parseInt(sCurrentval.trim());
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }else{
        System.out.println("Reading Value  null ");
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    try {
        if (br != null)br.close();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Which line is giving the NullPointerException? You should be able to see that in the stacktrace.

Comment: The `while` will skip over the whole file. `sCurrentval` can only be null afterwards

Comment: @ Daniel Lerps - its absolute path of file

Comment: Write the stack trace

Comment: See the updated answer it may help you

Answer (score 1):

Your `BufferedReader br = null;` with in the `try`. But your `finally` also using the same variable `br`.

```
 try
    {
    //
    BufferedReader br = null; // declared with in try
    //
    }
    finally {
    try {
    if (br != null) // In this line the br is not identified 
     br.close();
    } catch (IOException ex) 
    {
    ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Try to declare the BufferReader outside the `try`

```
BufferedReader br = null;
```

And then your while loop is only for the printing the value of the variable. Include the below if else condition within the while and then try the below code.

```
while ((sCurrentval = br.readLine()) != null)
            {
                System.out.println("Reading from File " + sCurrentval);
                if (sCurrentval != null && !sCurrentval.trim().isEmpty())
                {
                    try
                    {
                        val = Integer.parseInt(sCurrentval.trim());
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("Reading Value  null ");
                }
            }
```